# Saving apostrophes in re.sub in Python

Tags: python, string, python-re

I want to save just normal letters and apostrophes with re.sub command in Python, however right now my code removes apostrophes so don't becomes dont etc. Can i add a "save" of apostrophes to my re.sub command or do I have to use some other solution?

My code right now:

```py
text = open("songs/"+artist+"/"+album+"/"+song, "r", encoding="latin-1")
lines = text.readlines()
for line in lines:
    line = line.lower()
    line = re.sub('[^a-z ]', '', line)
    words = line.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```py
re.sub('[^a-z ]', '', line)
```

is taking all characters that are not (`^`) either lowercase `a-z`, or space  , and removing them (by replacing them with `''`)

You want to add apostrophes to the list of characters that are preserved. In order to do so, you can either **escape** the single-quote/apostrophe character in your regex:

```py
re.sub('[^a-z \']', '', line)
```

or use double-quotes in the string for your regex:

```py
re.sub("[^a-z ']", '', line)
```

---

**separate comment**

By the way, a modern way of filling in a string with variables is with an f-string ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings)). Instead of

```py
"songs/"+artist+"/"+album+"/"+song
```

you can use

```py
f"songs/{artist}/{album}/{song}"
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks Zev, also for the additional comment. Looks more smooth that way.